# Host WordPress and ReactJS in the same Apache Server

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, apache, wp-graphql

Can this be doable to serve WordPress and ReactJS in the same server.

I have a ReactJS App that is running in http://127.0.0.1:3000/ and a WordPress' root directory is located at "D:/var/www/html/website".

The ReactJS App will going to use http://loc.website.com/ as well as the WordPress. To prevent WordPress from conflicting the http://loc.website.com/, it has only limited URL path (**`/wp-admin, /sm-admin, /graphql, /wp-login.php`**) as a valid url to undergo D:/var/www/html/website/index.php.

This is my current virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/var/www/html/website"
    ServerName loc.website.com
    ErrorLog "logs/loc.website.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/loc.website.com-access.log" common

    <Directory "D:/var/www/html/website">
        Require local
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
        Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
    </Directory>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(_next/webpack-hmr)$  ws://127.0.0.1:3000/$1
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    <LocationMatch "^/(wp-admin|sm-admin|graphql|wp-login.php)">
        ProxyPass !
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Wordpress D:/var/www/html/website/.htaccess contains this config as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this possible to implement? If not, I have a working separated domains for both app which is working fine.

Thanks for any answers.